# One table with Nulls vs two tables

Tags: mysql, null

Let's say I have a simple situation. I have `user` table for my website and I need to place somewhere activation codes for email verification.

What is better option:

1. `activation_code` column in `user` table, which means I'll get NULLs or useless data when email is already verified. But on the other hand, I'm sure, I have only one code per user and one table less.
2. Separate table for codes. No useless data or NULLs. But an additional table for one column ( + user_id).

Because I try not to use any NULLs ( that's because I was taught so, not sure if rightly), I would prefer 2nd option. But I've seen first way in many web apps, so that's why I'm giving this question.

Comment: I'd go for a second table, with date of creation, and multiple codes per user. The times people just re-request validation is enormous, only to then find the first e-mail in their spambox, or just delayed. I like to be able to give them more then one, and invalidate them based on time later.

Comment: @Wrikken Thanks for the answer and moreover thanks for advice about users behavior, which is obvious true but I haven't thought about this till now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advocate for the separate table because in my opinion it models the data better. And it also allows you to generate multiple activation codes for the same user - this can come in handy!

On the other hand, I totally disagree with the practice of not using NULLs. I know some people advocate steering clear of them for reasons which can usually be attributed to laziness but the reality is that NULLs can be very useful in modeling data! They have a purpose which is to represent **missing data** or **unknown values** and they should definitely be used for this purpose!